# Using html table data in .js calculations and updating cells as a result

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to link the table in the following code to the form and the script. I need to work out the monthly repayment in each row based on the value in the "initial rate" column (and using the calculation already in the script to find var repayment, but am struggling to find a way to get a cell to update, and how to find a way to parse each of the "initial rate " values in an elegant way.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

}

function repayment() {

  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;

  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
  document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

}
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  <div align="center">
    <br />

    <p>
      Home Value £
      <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Loan Amount £
      <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Interest Rate
      <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
    </p>

    Term
    <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
    <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>
    <p>
      <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Mortgage Lender</th>
    <th>Max LTV</th>
    <th>SVR</th>
    <th>Fee</th>
    <th>Max Amount</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Length (months)</th>
    <th>Initial Rate</th>
    <th>Monthly Repayment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Halifax</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>999</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HSBC</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3.49</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.49</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nationwide</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>199</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>1.49</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yorkshire Building Society</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>2.49</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Direct</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>999</td>
    <td>750000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

We simply loop through the table rows and get the list of cells for each row.

- Using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), we can quickly access elements, targeting them by using css selectors.
- Using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), we can access the text value of a cell.
- Using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), we can parse the *initial rate*.

I would also assign an id to the table to make sure it selects the right one, in the form of:

```
var rows = querySelectorAll('table#myTableId tr')
```

Example code, going at the end of `repayment()`:

```js
// get the rows
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
for(var row of rows) {

    // get the cells
    var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');

    // skip headers, essentially
    if(cells.length == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    /*  cells[x]:
        [0] Mortgage Lender
        [1] Max LTV
        [2] SVR
        [3] Fee
        [4] Max Amount
        [5] Type
        [6] Length (months)
        [7] Initial Rate
        [8] Monthly Repayment
    */

    // get initial rate
    var iniRate = parseFloat(cells[7].textContent);

    /*
        calculate row stuff here
    */

    // update "Monthly Repayment" cell
    cells[8].textContent = 'new value';
}
```